# export an excel file in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my code for exporting .csv, .xls, .txt and .xml files. it works properly, but in excel file exporting, it saves as a tab delimited file. i cannaot import the file again in the database. please help me to export the excel file.

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php"); 

    if ($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"]) { 
        $strOutput = "";
        $line_terminated="\r\n";
        $strDatas = array();
        $field_terminated = doSelectDelimiterValue($_POST);             
        $strExportValue = "Name".$field_terminated."Code".$field_terminated."Email".$field_terminated."Designation".$field_terminated."Salary";
        $strSelectQuery = doSelectCsv();
        $strDatas = $strSelectQuery;

        if ($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
            $strOutput.= '';
            $strOutput.= '<employee_details>'.$line_terminated;
        } else {
            $strOutput.= $strExportValue;
        }

        if($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="TXT") {
            $strDelimeter = '\t';
        } else {
            $strDelimeter = '';
        }
        $strOutput.= doExportData($_POST, $strDatas, $line_terminated, $field_terminated, $strDelimeter);

        if ($_POST["frmDownloadFiles"] =="XML") {
            $strOutput.= '</employee_details>';
        }
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        doHeader($_POST, $strOutput);

        echo $strOutput;
        exit;
    }

    function doSelectCsv()
    {
        $strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member";
        $strResult = SelectQry($strSql);
        return $strResult;
    }

    function doExportData($objArray, $strDatas, $line_terminated, $field_terminated, $strDelimeter = NULL)
    {
        for ($k=0; $k<count($strDatas); $k++) {
            if ($objArray["frmDownloadFiles"] == "XML") {
                $strOutput.= '<Row>';
                $strOutput.= $line_terminated;
                $strOutput.= '<name>'.$strDatas[$k]['1'].'</name>'.$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= '<code>'.$strDatas[$k]['2'].'</code>'.$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= '<mail>'.$strDatas[$k]['3'].'</mail>'.$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= '<designation>'.$strDatas[$k]['4'].'</designation>'.$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= '<salary>'.$strDatas[$k]['5'].'</salary>'.$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= '</Row>'.$field_terminated;
            } else {
                $strOutput.= $line_terminated;
                $strOutput.= $strDatas[$k]['1'].$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= $strDatas[$k]['2'].$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= $strDatas[$k]['3'].$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= $strDatas[$k]['4'].$field_terminated;
                $strOutput.= $strDatas[$k]['5'].$strDelimeter;
            }
        }
        return $strOutput;
    }

    function doSelectDelimiterValue($objArray)
    {
        switch ($objArray["frmDownloadFiles"]) {
            case "CSV":
                echo $field_terminated= ",";
                break;
            case "XLS":
                echo $field_terminated= "\t";
                break;
            case "TXT":
                echo $field_terminated= "   ";
                break;
            case "XML":
                echo $field_terminated= "\r\n";
                break;
        }
        return $field_terminated;
    }

    function doHeader($objArray, $strOutput)
    {
        switch ($objArray["frmDownloadFiles"]) {
            case "CSV":
                header("Content-Type: application/csv");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export_csv.csv");
                break;
            case "XLS":
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=export_excel.xls");
                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
                break;

            case "TXT":
                header("Content-Type: application/txt");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export_text.txt");
                break;
            case "XML":
                header("Content-Type: application/xml");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export_xml.xml");
                break;
        }
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($strOutput));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Export Files</title>
<link href="css/export.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<form id="frmEmployee" name="frmEmployee" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validation();">
<div class="all">
<div class="alls">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="top">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="text" align="center">
          <p class="det">DOWNLOAD FILES</p>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download CSV file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="CSV" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download excel file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="XLS" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download text file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="TXT" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="nnn">
        <div class="name">Download xml file:</div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>
          <input type="submit" name="frmDownloadFiles" id="frmDownloadFiles" value="XML" class="subb" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to create files in native Excel format, you'll need to search for a PHP extension.

Comment: when i download the excel file, it download as an excel file. but i import the downloaded file again into database, it cannot imported, it gives the error "The filename /tmp/phpTkNQFL is not readable"

Comment: Presently, you're writing data in some arbitrary format to an XLS file. The computer will identify the file as Excel because of the .xls extension, but it doesn't mean that it's in Excel format. Again, to write an XLS file properly, you will have to search for a PHP extension that does this. XLS is more complicated than CSV or XML; you can't do it by hand.

Comment: how can i import the downloaded excel file?... please help me...

Comment: how can i give the php extension using this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML coding:

```
<input type="submit" name="frmDownload" id="frmDownload" value="CSV" title="Export" class="frmDownloadButton" />
<input type="submit" name="frmDownload" id="frmDownload" value="Excel" title="Export" class="frmDownloadButton" />
<input type="submit" name="frmDownload" id="frmDownload" value="TEXT" title="Export" class="frmDownloadButton" />
<input type="submit" name="frmDownload" id="frmDownload" value="XML" title="Export" class="frmDownloadButton" />
```

PHP routine:

```
if ($_POST["frmDownload"]) { 
    $output = "";
    $line_terminated="\r\n";
    $strDatas = array();
    $field_terminated = doGetFieldDelimeter($_POST);
    $export_schema = "Name".$field_terminated."Code".$field_terminated."Email".$field_terminated."Designation".$field_terminated."Number".$field_terminated."Salary".$field_terminated."Age";
    $strDataQuery = doSelectRecords();
    $strDatas = $strDataQuery;
    $output.= doGetExportSchema($_POST,$export_schema);
    $delimeter = doGetDelimeterForTextFile($_POST);
    $output.= doExportData($_POST, $strDatas, $field_terminated, $line_terminated, $delimeter);
    $output.= doGetXmlTitle($_POST);
    doGetHeader($_POST,$output,$objPHPExcel);
    echo $output;
    exit;
}
```

functions:

```
function doSelectRecords()
{
    $strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee";
    $strResult = SelectQry($strSql);
    return $strResult;
}


function SelectQry($Qry) {
    $result = mysql_query($Qry) or die ("QUERY Error:".$Qry."<br>".mysql_error());      
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
    if ($numrows == 0) {            
        return;
    } else {
       $row = array(); 
       $record = array();
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $record[] = $row; 
       }        
    }   
    return MakeStripSlashes($record);
}

function doGetExportSchema($objArray,$export_schema)
{

    if ($objArray["frmDownload"] =="XML") {
        $output.= '';
        $output.= '<employee>';
    } else {
        $output.= $export_schema;
    }
    return $output;
}

function doGetDelimeterForTextFile($objArray)
{
    if($objArray["frmDownload"] =="TEXT") {
        $delimeter = '\t';
    } else {
        $delimeter = '';
    }
    return $delimeter;
}

function doExportData($objArray,$strDatas,$field_terminated,$line_terminated,$delimeter = NULL)
{

    for ($k=0; $k<count($strDatas); $k++) {
        $strData = $strDatas[$k];
        if ($objArray["frmDownload"] == "XML") {
            $output.= $line_terminated;
            $output.= '<row>';
            $output.= $line_terminated;
            $output.= '<name>'.$strData['1'].'</name>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '<code>'.$strData['2'].'</code>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '<email>'.$strData['3'].'</email>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '<designation>'.$strData['4'].'</designation>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '<number>'.$strData['5'].'</number>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '<salary>'.$strData['6'].'</salary>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '<age>'.$strData['7'].'</age>'.$field_terminated;
            $output.= '</row>'.$field_terminated;
        } else {
            $output.= $line_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['1'].$field_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['2'].$field_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['3'].$field_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['4'].$field_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['5'].$field_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['6'].$field_terminated;
            $output.= $strData['7'].$delimeter;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}


function doGetFieldDelimeter($objArray) 
{

    switch ($objArray["frmDownload"]) {
        case "CSV":
            echo $field_terminated= ",";
            break;
        case "Excel":
            echo $field_terminated="\t";
            break;
        case "TEXT":
            echo $field_terminated="|";
            break;
        case "XML":
            echo $field_terminated="\r\n";
            break;
    }
    return $field_terminated;
}

function doGetXmlTitle($objArray)
{
    if ($objArray["frmDownload"] == "XML") {
        $output.= '</employee>';
    }
    return $output;
}

function doGetHeader($objArray,$output,$objPHPExcel = NULL)
{
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    switch ($objArray["frmDownload"]) {
        case "CSV":
            header("Content-Type: application/csv");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee_details.csv");
            break;
        case "Excel":
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Type: application/download");;
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Report.xls");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
            break;
        case "TEXT":
            header("Content-Type: application/txt");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee_details.txt");
            break;
        case "XML":
            header("Content-Type: application/xml");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee_details.xml");
            break;
    }
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
}
```

Pass required value in $objPHPExcel for getting exact result what u need it, atfirst download PHPExcel and include it in your library files.

keep ahead with this following routine for PHPExcel to write .xls formatted file.

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);  
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

I hope this is answer for your question...

Answer (score 0):

step1: go to ->>>>>https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php

Step2:Download Spreadsheet folder, Pear.php file and System.php file
from https://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/download

Step3: include in you php file all the above downloads in right order
 Step4: Write this code in php

```
require_once '/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
$target_dir = PRODUCT_PAINT_EXPORT_PATH;//(where u want to save your export file)
//            $randno = rand(100000, 999999);
            $randno = rand(1, 100);
            $fileName = 'product_paint' . $randno;
            global $db;
            $productList = array();

            $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer($target_dir . $fileName . '.xls');



            $ProductPaintsColl = $db->product_paints;
            $ProductPaintsDoc = $ProductPaintsColl->find(array(), array('_id' => 1, 'name' => 1, 'brand' => 1, 'group' => 1, 'category' => 1, 'application_area' => 1, 'coverage' => 1, 'finish' => 1, 'sqft_price' => 1, 'features' => 1));

            if ($ProductPaintsDoc != null)
            {
                foreach ($ProductPaintsDoc as $doc)
                {
                    array_push($productList, array(
                        'Id' => $doc['_id']->{'$id'},
                        'Name' => $doc['name'],
                        'Brand' => $doc['brand'],
                        'Group' => $doc['group'],
                        'Category' => $doc['category'],
                        'Application_area' => $doc['application_area'],
                        'Coverage' => $doc['coverage'],
                        'Finish' => $doc['finish'],
                        'Sqft_price' => $doc['sqft_price'],
                        'Features' => $doc['features'],
                    ));
                }
            }

            $worksheet = & $workbook->addWorksheet('Paint Data');

            $worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Product Id');
            $worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Name');
            $worksheet->write(0, 2, 'Brand');
            $worksheet->write(0, 3, 'Group');
            $worksheet->write(0, 4, 'Category');
            $worksheet->write(0, 5, 'application_area');
            $worksheet->write(0, 6, 'coverage');
            $worksheet->write(0, 7, 'finish');
            $worksheet->write(0, 8, 'sqft_price');
            $worksheet->write(0, 9, 'features');
            $num_row = count($productList);


            for ($i = 0; $i <= $num_row; $i++)
            {
                $j = 0;
                $ii = $i + 1;
                foreach ($productList[$i] as $key => $value)
                {
                    $worksheet->write($ii, $j, $value);


                    $j++;
                }
            }
            $workbook->close();
```